# What is the meaning of the error message "Use of uninitialized value in null operation" in Perl?

Tags: perl

What does the error message "Use of uninitialized value in null operation" mean in Perl?

I have googled this extensively and found many pages where people discussed an error of this form. However, despite my searches I have been unable to understand what error condition this indicates. Please note: I do not have source code which I can share which demonstrates this error, since it is only occurring in a test script when running under "Test::More", and involves large amounts of XS code. I would just like to get some idea what this error message might mean.

Comment: I presume you are asking about the "null" part specifically, right?

Comment: I would expect "Use of uninitialized value in subroutine entry" for a warning from XS. I don't know why it would say "void".

Comment: @ikegami - yes, I am very specifically trying to understand what this exact error message, worded exactly as in the title, means.

Answer (score 2):

Look in [`perldoc perldiag`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html) for 'Use of uninitialized value'.

- `Use of uninitialized value%s`

  (W uninitialized) An undefined value was used as if it were already defined. It was interpreted as a "" or a 0, but maybe it was a mistake. To suppress this warning assign a defined value to your variables.

  To help you figure out what was undefined, perl will try to tell you the name of the variable (if any) that was undefined. In some cases it cannot do this, so it also tells you what operation you used the undefined value in. Note, however, that perl optimizes your program anid the operation displayed in the warning may not necessarily appear literally in your program. For example, "that $foo" is usually optimized into "that " . $foo , and the warning will refer to the concatenation (.) operator, even though there is no . in your program.

The interesting part is working out what the 'in null operation' means.  It is not as simple as:

```
my $x;
$x;
```

That gets:

```
Useless use of private variable in void context
```

At this stage, I'm not sure; you could help by showing the Perl script that triggered the message.

---

After looking at the Perl source (something I normally avoid doing), there are a number of tests which contain comments such as (`t/lib/dbmt_common.pl`):

```
# Bug ID 20001013.009
#
# test that $hash{KEY} = undef doesn't produce the warning
#     Use of uninitialized value in null operation
```

You can also find references to the 'null operation' in `regen/opcodes`.  The null operation appears to be opcode 0.

```
# Nothing.

null        null operation      ck_null     0
stub        stub            ck_null     0
scalar      scalar          ck_fun      s%  S

# Pushy stuff.

pushmark    pushmark        ck_null     s0
```

If you look in `opcode.h`, you can find:

```
#ifndef DOINIT
EXTCONST char* const PL_op_name[];
#else
EXTCONST char* const PL_op_name[] = {
    "null",
    "stub",
    "scalar",
    "pushmark",

...


#ifndef DOINIT
EXTCONST char* const PL_op_desc[];
#else
EXTCONST char* const PL_op_desc[] = {
    "null operation",
    "stub", 
    "scalar",
    "pushmark",
```

The file `cpan/Encode/lib/Encode/Encoding.pm` contains the comment (in some POD):

```
=item -E<gt>renewed

Predefined As:

  sub renewed { $_[0]->{renewed} || 0 }

Tells whether the object is renewed (and how many times).  Some
modules emit C<Use of uninitialized value in null operation> warning
unless the value is numeric so return 0 for false.
```

I think you might do better asking at [PerlMonks](http://perlmonks.org/) or some similar place where the the gurus of the internals of Perl hang out.

Comment: I believe he's asking about "null" specifically. An XS coder surely knows what the general form of the message means. You should delete your answer to encourage people with the legitimate answer to read the question.

Comment: I'd like to thank you Jonathon Leffler for the effort you have made to answer this, including looking through the Perl source code. However, the honest truth is that I am still rather baffled. I think your suggestion to try Perl Monks is a valid and useful one.